# seaborn lineplot set x-axis scale interval for visibility

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Here's how plot this figure:

```py
plt.figure(1, figsize = (20,8))
ax = sns.lineplot(data=df, x=df['timestamp'], y=df['speed'])

plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.title('Trip 543365 timeline', fontsize=22)
plt.ylabel('GPS speed', fontsize=18)
plt.xlabel('Timestamp', fontsize=16,)
plt.savefig('trip537685', dpi=600)
```

[image]

The `x-axis` is not readable despite setting `plt.xticks(rotation=90)`, how to I change the scale so it appears readable?

Comment: Maybe you could change your time data to pandas datetime format and let seaborn/matplotlib automatically set appropriate ticks? When the data is given in string format, too many ticks make the plot unreadable. Note that your post is missing reproducible data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have not provided the data, I have taken some random data of ~1500 rows with datetime as DD-MM-YYYY format. First, as this is in text, change it to datetime using `to_datetime()`, then plot it. That should, as @JohanC said, give you fairly good result. But, if you still need to adjust it, use `set_major_locator()` and `set_major_formatter()` to adjust as you need. I have shown this as interval of 3 months. You can, however, adjust it as you see fit. Hope this helps.

```
df=pd.read_csv('austin_weather.csv')
df.rename(columns={'Date': 'timestamp'}, inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={'TempHighF': 'speed'}, inplace=True)

df['timestamp']=pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'],format="%d-%m-%Y")

plt.figure(1, figsize = (20,8))
ax = sns.lineplot(data=df, x=df['timestamp'], y=df['speed'])

import matplotlib.dates as mdates
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=3))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b-%Y'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a lot of datapoints plotted so that the xticks just get overlayed due to the label font size.

If you don't need every single x-ticks displayed you can set the label locations with [`xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) along with an array to display only every nth tick.

**Data preparation:**
Just strings for x-axis lables as an example.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import random
import string


def random_string():
    return ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase +
                   string.digits, k=7))


size=1000
x_list = []

for i in range(size):
    x_list.append(random_string())

y = np.random.randint(low=0, high=50, size=size)

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(x_list, y)),
                  columns =['timestamp', 'speed'])
```

**Plot with a lot of datapoints *for reference*:**

```
plt.figure(1, figsize = (20,8))
ax = sns.lineplot(data=df, x=df['timestamp'], y=df['speed'])

plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.title('Trip 543365 timeline', fontsize=22)
plt.ylabel('GPS speed', fontsize=18)
plt.xlabel('Timestamp', fontsize=16,)

plt.show()
```

[image]

**Plot with reduced xticks:**

```
plt.figure(1, figsize = (20,8))
ax = sns.lineplot(data=df, x=df['timestamp'], y=df['speed'])

plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.title('Trip 543365 timeline', fontsize=22)
plt.ylabel('GPS speed', fontsize=18)
plt.xlabel('Timestamp', fontsize=16,)

every_nth_xtick = 50
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, len(x_list)+1, every_nth_xtick))

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

To cross check you can add:

```
print(x_list[0])
print(x_list[50])
print(x_list[100])
```

Just make sure it's within the same random call.